# All integers in the series will lie in the range [-10^6,+10^6] means?

Tags: php, regex, integer, range

I found the one of the condition as "All integers in the series will lie in the range

[-10^6,+10^6]" in one of the online test what does it means?

Comment: Probably this is not the place to ask questions like this....

Comment: Tip: 10^6 means ten to the power 6.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about elementary mathematics.  Given the specific question, it might be off-topic on the alternate sites too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia page on intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Terminology) you can see;

> A closed interval includes its endpoints, and is denoted with square brackets. For example [0,1] means greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 1.

10^6 (10 to the power of 6) is the same as 1 million, so `All integers in the series will lie in the range
[-10^6,+10^6]` means that all numbers in the series are;

- Greater than or equal to -1000000 (minus one million)
- Less than or equal to 1000000 (one million)